# How to simulate expanding effect in bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this react code:

```
const[open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const zoom = () => {
    if(open){
        setOpen(false);
    }
    else{
        setOpen(true);
    }
}

return (
    <div><button>zoom in and out</button></div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className={`col col-${open ? '12' : '9'}`}>
            Content than can be expanded    
        </div>
        {
            !open && 
        <div className="col col-3">
            content that gets hidden when zooming in
        </div>  
        }
    </div>

)
```

By default you see 2 columns. The main that is 9/12. The right that is 3/12.
When button is clicked, the main column will become 12/12, hence taking up all the space of the row.
While the one that is 3/12 hides.

This works. But it is not a good effect. I would like to have some kind of animation. Like having the main div expanding to take over all the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change `col-12` to `col-9` and vice versa, you are infact changing the `width` of the `div` element.

Dom Elements, `HTMLDivElement` in this particular case, has a `style` attribute which is of type `React.CSSProperties`. Using the `style` attribute and the `transition` property, animate the `width` of the div element.

`style={{transition: "width 0.5s"}}`

```
<div className={`col col-${open ? '12' : '9'}`} 
     style={{transition: "width 0.5s"}}>
```

#### Full code

```
const App = () => {
 const[open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
 const zoom = () => setOpen(!open)

 return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={zoom}>zoom in and out</button>
      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div style={{transition: "width 0.5s"}} className={`bg-primary col col-${open ? '12' : '9'}`}>
              Content than can be expanded
          </div>
          {
              !open && 
          <div className="col col-3">
           content that gets hidden when zooming in
          </div>  
          }
      </div>   
    </div>  
   </>)
}
```

#### Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Thanks. But there is an issue. When I zoom in, the content of 3/12 disappear immediately. Fair enough. However, when I zoom out, the content of 3/12 will first appear in the next row. And only when the main col becomes 9/12 it will move up.

Comment: I tried by making sure the 3/12 always is in the DOM. But with display block/none and transition. But I get the samme effect with the 3/12 col moving up only when transition is complete.

Comment: That is expected. Try to zoom stackoverflow by Ctrl + + and see the right navbar moves below the main. It is because there is not enough space.

Comment: That is not related to your question. You should better accept the answer again as it correctly addresses you concerns.